# Angular Material: using mat-sidenav, cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have an Angular 8 project with Angular Material 8 that cannot toggle the sidenav via a button in the same component. The javascript console says that

> cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

but the sidenav has the reference variable in the template.

I have made sure the button is in the template so that I don't have to worry about event emitters or other trickery. This should be straightforward.

**HTML**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async)"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
  <span>This Be Me App, Matey</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" *ngIf="isAuthenticated()"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'false' : 'true'">
    <mat-toolbar><mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()" *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async)">arrow_back</mat-icon> Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
      <a mat-list-item (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="content">    
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The menu button appears and disappears at the breakpoint like expected, but clicking it gives the error.

What should happen is that the button only appears when you get below the `isHandset$` break (which happens) and then it should open over the top of the content (which doesn't happen). Since the `#sidenav` reference variable is in the `mat-sidenav` tag it seems like I've got it set up properly.

Comment: Can you throw this in a stackblitz?

Comment: Is your `isAuthenticated()` true by the time you try to call `sidenav.toggle()`?

Comment: @Jojofoulk yes. That method looks for a token in local storage and checks the expiration date. If it's not expired, then isAuthenticated() = true. I've checked that in the Chrome debugger. 

I'll get it up on Stackblitz.

Comment: Ugh. Aside from the icons not displaying on stackblitz, the example works. :-/  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vppsa3

Answer (score 2):

the error you shared must have a dependency or something missing; to see the working behavior, we had to address the 2 `*ngIf` conditions in your code:

- `isAuthenticated()` -- which could be false, we don't know the logic you had used
- `(isHandset$ | async)` -- we don't know the observable logic

assuming these 2 `*ngIf` conditions to be true, the code works fine... no error of 'cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined'

relevant **ts**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-open-close-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-open-close-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-open-close-example.css'],
})
export class SidenavOpenCloseExample {
  events: string[] = [];
  opened: boolean;
  isHandset$:boolean =true;
  isAuthenticated(){ return true;}

  shouldRun = [/(^|\.)plnkr\.co$/, /(^|\.)stackblitz\.io$/].some(h => h.test(window.location.host));
}
```

you can check [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9mcz7v)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It appears that clicking the button works exactly once for me in stackblitz but not a second time, and I get that same error. I'm still tinkering with it.